# Disable fsck messages during boot

Tags: 16.04, grub2, plymouth, kiosk

I'm attempting to make boot Ubuntu as a kiosk and I'm very very close. I've got the splash screens setup for grub and a new theme for plymouth. They work and look great. I do have a couple issues remaining.

The main one appears to be a message from `fsck` during boot:
`/dev/sda2: clean, xxx/xxxx files, xxxx/xxxxx blocks`
This removes the splash screen and shows text instead. I have tried adding `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=console=tty11` expecting it to print output to a different console than the splash, but instead it just disabled the splash entirely.

The other issue isn't all that important. There is a blank screen after the rub splash, and the kernel boot splash. What is this, and is there a way to fill it ?

**Edit:**

I replaced `quiet` with `loglevel=2` and instead of the single `/dev/sda2: clean` statement, I get the system boot up text instead. So it gets worse.

However I did add `fsck.mode=skip` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` and that got rid of the message. Not sure I'm comfortable with skipping the fsck though. I will keep investigating.

Comment: It should be easily surpressed with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet"` in `/etc/default/grub` ... If you'd like do surpress more, you'll need to check `loglevel=[n]` instead of quiet. 'loglevel=4' should be the same as 'quiet'

Comment: Those appear to be exactly what I'm looking for, but when I set `loglevel=3` and remove `quite` same with level 0 or 7 I actually get more text. What are these options called, and where can I look up what all the options are?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2UnixI think this is a duplicate of that question. Should I ask for clarification here, or in that thread?

Comment: @Apeiron You can simply say the duplicate doesn't work for you because of _____ here and I will retract the duplicate vote. You cannot ask for clarification on the duplicate candidate. How often is the kiosk rebooted? Is an employee around when it is rebooted? Is it only patrons that see the reboot screen?

Comment: I got through some more of the answer and I was able to get the message to go away, I just wanted to make sure the `fsck` was still being run, this is what I wanted clarification on.

Comment: Did you ever keep investigating and find a way to solve the issue?

Comment: @semitones yes, it's been a while but IIRC the fsck was moved to a systemd service, and the systemd text was masked. I need to go through this soon as well, send me a remind and I'll try to update with what worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend disabling *fsck* indefinitely since it exists to protect the integrity of your drive and repairs any issues as and when necessary, so it really needs to run periodically and it runs at startup because the filesystem must be unmounted for it to run the filesystem checks.  However you could set *fsck* to only run say every d/w/m period, say 3 months, 6 months, though I personally wouldn't like the idea that the integrity of my drive would only be checked every 6 months, I would recommend setting aside a period of planned downtime for your kiosk per week, per month or whatever suits you best and set the check to run at some specific date and time.

You can tune the filesystem checks to suit your needs using tune2fs, which allows you to adjust tunable filesystem parameters on ext2/ext3/ext4 filesystems:

```
$ tune2fs
tune2fs 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
Usage: tune2fs 
    [-c max_mounts_count] [-e errors_behavior] [-f] [-g group]
    [-i interval[d|m|w]] [-j] [-J journal_options] [-l]
    [-m reserved_blocks_percent] [-o [^]mount_options[,...]]
    [-r reserved_blocks_count] [-u user] [-C mount_count]
    [-L volume_label] [-M last_mounted_dir]
    [-O [^]feature[,...]] [-Q quota_options]
    [-E extended-option[,...]] [-T last_check_time] [-U UUID]
    [-I new_inode_size] [-z undo_file] device
```

The specific tune2fs options that allow you may want to change are:

```
-c max-mount-counts - Adjust  the  number  of  mounts  after  which the filesystem will be checked by e2fsck(8).  If max-mount-counts is 0 or -1, the number of times the filesystem is mounted will be disregarded by e2fsck(8) and the kernel.
-i interval-between-checks[d|m|w] - Adjust the maximal time between two filesystem checks.
```

To first check what the current parameters of your fsck are you can run the following command:

```
$ sudo tune2fs -l /dev/sda2 | egrep -i 'mount count|check'
```

For example to modify the check-interval to only check after 100 mounts or a 3 month period:

```
$ tune2fs -c 100 -i 3m /dev/sda2
```

The issue with the blank screen after the splash, I am not sure what would be causing that.

This article may also be of some use to you:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Silent_boot

Comment: I agree that disabling the check is a bad idea and I'm fine with it checking every boot. I just can't have it print a message to the screen, I need to keep the splash screen up. Logging to a file would be preffered.